# How to edit the path in odbcinst -j

Tags: python, sql-server, ubuntu-14.04

when I view this `odbcinst -j` it shows

```
unixODBC 2.2.14
DRIVERS............: /etc/unixODBC/odbcinst.ini
SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /etc/unixODBC/odbc.ini
FILE DATA SOURCES..: /etc/unixODBC/ODBCDataSources
USER DATA SOURCES..: /etc/unixODBC/odbc.ini
SQLULEN Size.......: 8
SQLLEN Size........: 8
SQLSETPOSIROW Size.: 8
```

But there is no location `/etc/unixODBC/odbcinst.ini`. The actual location is `/etc/odbcinst.ini` so I need to change the location. How can I do it?

I'm trying to run below script

```
import pyodbc 
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQLServer};SERVER=10.10.10.1;DATABASE=ABC;UID=username;PWD=password')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
```

But it shows the following error

```
 pyodbc.Error: ('IM002', '[IM002] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

and I added the odbc.in and odbcinst.ini file information as follows

```
cat odbc.ini
[SQLServer]
Description     = ODBC for MSSQL
Driver          = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libodbcmyS.so
Servername      = 
Database        = 
UID             = 
Port            = 1433

cat /etc/odbcinst.ini
[SQLServer]
Description     = ODBC for MSSQL
Driver          = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libodbcmyS.so
Setup           = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libmyodbc.so
UsageCount      = 1
FileUsage       = 1
```

I hope the problem is in `odbcinst -j` when I show it it displays the wrong path.  I don't know how to fix.?

Comment: is this post helpful? http://denverpsmith.com/posts/connecting-to-mssql-database-from-linuxmac

Comment: I'm confused as to which database you want to connect to, can you please confirm:  you've tagged this question as sql-server but your driver setup looks to be using mysql.  The drivers, as I recall, for sql-server are named something like libtdsodbc.so not libodbcmyS.so. Perhaps this is your issue?

Comment: I don't know the product that you are asking about, but you wrote: "But there is no location /etc/unixODBC/odbcinst.ini. The actual location is /etc/odbcinst.ini so I need to change the location." If that's all you want to do, I would just add a symbolic link:
If the directory doesn't exist, then:
    $ mkdir /etc/unixODBC
    $ cd
    /etc/unixODBC
    $ pwd
    /etc/unixODBC
    $ ln -s /etc/odbcinst.ini .
    $ ls -l 
    lrwxrwxrwx  ... odbcinst.ini -> /etc/unixODBC/odbcinst.ini

Comment: @ThomasHedden Yep I tried it. I created the directory and copied the files. But it is also didn't work.

Comment: Have you properly exported the right environmental variables? Maybe you could put them in your `.bashrc` or similar file. `export ODBCINI=/etc/odbc.ini` and
`export ODBCSYSINI=/etc` so that can point to the right files? If that works, I'll write up...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It looks like the "default" path is not set correctly.
I'm pretty sure you're already doing it as it is mentioned in different places, but I want to remind that you should set the right environmental variables as described in the following links:
http://www.raosoft.com/ezsurvey/help/2007/odbc_in_unix.html
http://gemfirexd.docs.pivotal.io/1.3.0/userguide/developers_guide/topics/odbc/install_config_odbc.html
It means that in your case, you could add a couple of lines to your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` or similar so that the program points to the right locations every time you would open your shell.
The lines to add would be then:

```
export ODBCINI=/etc/odbc.ini
export ODBCSYSINI=/etc
```

---

Looking indeed at the source code of **unixODBC-2.2.14-p2** package, when invoking `odbcinst -j` it will go through the following branch in the code

```
case 'j':
    PrintConfigInfo();
    exit(0);
```

and `PrintConfigInfo()` will do the job of printing a bunch of info, specifically what you see

```
void PrintConfigInfo()
{
    char szFileName[ODBC_FILENAME_MAX+1];
        char b1[ 256 ], b2[ 256 ];

    printf( "unixODBC " VERSION "\n" );

    *szFileName = '\0';
    sprintf( szFileName, "%s/odbcinst.ini", odbcinst_system_file_path( b1 ), odbcinst_system_file_name( b2 ));
    printf( "DRIVERS............: %s\n", szFileName );

    *szFileName = '\0';
    _odbcinst_SystemINI( szFileName, FALSE );
    printf( "SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: %s\n", szFileName );

    *szFileName = '\0';
    _odbcinst_FileINI( szFileName );
    printf( "FILE DATA SOURCES..: %s\n", szFileName );

    *szFileName = '\0';
    _odbcinst_UserINI( szFileName, FALSE );
    printf( "USER DATA SOURCES..: %s\n", szFileName );

    printf( "SQLULEN Size.......: %d\n", sizeof( SQLULEN ));
    printf( "SQLLEN Size........: %d\n", sizeof( SQLLEN ));
    printf( "SQLSETPOSIROW Size.: %d\n", sizeof( SQLSETPOSIROW ));
}
```

Now let's examine one of the print statements to understand where it gets the path from, let's take for example the line

```
printf( "SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: %s\n", szFileName );
```

where `szFileName` is set by the following call:

```
_odbcinst_SystemINI( szFileName, FALSE );
```

which is defined in the file `odbcinst/_odbcinst_SystemINI.c`:

```
BOOL _odbcinst_SystemINI( char *pszFileName, BOOL bVerify )
{
        FILE                    *hFile;
        char                    b1[ 256 ];

    sprintf( pszFileName, "%s/odbc.ini", odbcinst_system_file_path( b1 ));

        if ( bVerify )
        {
        /* try opening for read */
                hFile = uo_fopen( pszFileName, "r" );
                if ( hFile )
                        uo_fclose( hFile );
                else
        {
            /* does not exist so try creating it */
            hFile = uo_fopen( pszFileName, "w" );
            if ( hFile )
                uo_fclose( hFile );
            else
                return FALSE;
        }
        }

        return TRUE;
}
```

where it sets the string to be printed in the following line

```
sprintf( pszFileName, "%s/odbc.ini", odbcinst_system_file_path( b1 ));
```

To understand how `odbcinst_system_file_path( b1 )` sets this path we look at the source and one finds

```
  char *odbcinst_system_file_path( char *buffer )
{
    char *path;
    static char save_path[ 512 ];
    static int saved = 0;

    if ( saved ) {
            return save_path;
    }

    if (( path = getenv( "ODBCSYSINI" ))) {
                strcpy( buffer, path );
        strcpy( save_path, buffer );
        saved = 1;
        return buffer;
        }
#ifdef SYSTEM_FILE_PATH
    else {
        strcpy( save_path, SYSTEM_FILE_PATH );
        saved = 1;
        return SYSTEM_FILE_PATH;
        }
#else
    else {
        strcpy( save_path, "/etc" );
        saved = 1;
        return "/etc";
        }
#endif
}
```

which as you can see read the environmental variable through `getenv( "ODBCSYSINI" )`. Similar for others. Now, the original code has another branch but ends up doing a similar thing using customized functions.

Comment: Now it is shows the following error  `pyodbc.Error: ('IM004', "[IM004] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Driver's SQLAllocHandle on SQL_HANDLE_HENV failed (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")`

Comment: It might be related to the following? http://www.paulsprogrammingnotes.com/2014/06/im004-unixodbcdriver-managerdrivers.html  Could you check that?

Comment: I fixed it. Thank You friend for your help :)

Comment: @mkHun May I know how you fixed it?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the root of the error you are getting is because your .odbc.ini's DRIVER definition is not pointing to your odbcinst.ini's driver name.

It should be something like this:

```
cat odbc.ini
[SQLServer]
Description     = ODBC for MSSQL
Driver          = DRIVER_ISSUE
Servername      = 
Database        = 
UID             = 
Port            = 1433

cat /etc/odbcinst.ini
[DRIVER_ISSUE]
Description     = ODBC for MSSQL
Driver          = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libodbcmyS.so
Setup           = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libmyodbc.so
UsageCount      = 1
FileUsage       = 1
```

On top of this, I believe your driver(libodbcmyS.so) is NOT correct for SQL-Server. (Note: this answer depends on the symbolic link you've already added.)

Comment: Now it is shows the following error  `pyodbc.Error: ('IM004', "[IM004] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Driver's SQLAllocHandle on SQL_HANDLE_HENV failed (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")`

Answer (score 1):

Try this if you haven't reset your odbcinst.ini

```
cnx = pyodbc.connect(server=servername, database = DBname, user=Username,
                           tds_version='7.3',password=Password,port=portno,
                           driver='/usr/local/lib/libtdsodbc.so')
```