# MAC OSX - How to solve "Could not SQLConnect" error

Tags: sql-server, database, macos, freetds, unixodbc

I'm trying to connect to my sql server database but it's not working.

The freetds is working, see the command:

```
tsql -S myserver.database.windows.net -U myuser -P mypassword
```

output:

```
locale is "C/UTF-8/C/C/C/C"
locale charset is "UTF-8"
using default charset "UTF8"
1>
```

but when I try to run the command isql, it returns me error.

command:

```
isql -v MYSERVER myuser mypassword
```

output:

```
[IM002][unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect
```

**My files:**

freetds.conf:

```
#   $Id: freetds.conf,v 1.12 2007-12-25 06:02:36 jklowden Exp $
#
# This file is installed by FreeTDS if no file by the same 
# name is found in the installation directory.  
#
# For information about the layout of this file and its settings, 
# see the freetds.conf manpage "man freetds.conf".  

# Global settings are overridden by those in a database
# server specific section
[global]
    # TDS protocol version
    tds version = 8.0

    # Whether to write a TDSDUMP file for diagnostic purposes
    # (setting this to /tmp is insecure on a multi-user system)
;   dump file = /tmp/freetds.log
;   debug flags = 0xffff

    # Command and connection timeouts
;   timeout = 10
;   connect timeout = 10

    # If you get out-of-memory errors, it may mean that your client
    # is trying to allocate a huge buffer for a TEXT field.  
    # Try setting 'text size' to a more reasonable limit 
    text size = 64512

    # If you experience TLS handshake errors and are using openssl,
    # try adjusting the cipher list (don't surround in double or single quotes)
    # openssl ciphers = HIGH:!SSLv2:!aNULL:-DH

[MYSERVER]
   host = myserver.database.windows.net
   port = 1433
   tds version = 8.0
   client charset = UTF8
```

odbcinst.ini:

```
[FreeTDS]
Description = FreeTDS
Driver      = /usr/local/lib/libtdsodbc.so
Setup       = /usr/local/lib/libtdsodbc.so
UsageCount  = 1
Trace       = Yes
TraceFile   = /Users/giorgecaique/Documents/sql.log
```

odbc.ini:

```
[MYSERVER]
Description = MYSERVER
Driver      = FreeTDS
Database    = mydatabase
Server      = myserver.database.windows.net
UserName    = myuser
Password    = mypassword
TDS_Version = 8.0
```

Can anyone help me? I already saw a lot of tutorials of how to solve this, but none of it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In `odbc.ini` file, you need a `Servername` attribute which points to the name of the DSN in `freetds.conf`. Also, `8.0` is not a valid version (long story, see the docs), and it is `UTF-8` not `UTF8`. For example:

`freetds.conf`:

```
[MYSERVER]
   host = myserver.database.windows.net
   port = 1433
   tds version = 7.1
   client charset = UTF-8
```

And then in `odbc.ini`:

```
[MYSERVER]
Description = MYSERVER
Driver      = FreeTDS
Database    = mydatabase
Servername  = MYSERVER
UserName    = myuser
Password    = mypassword
TDS_Version = 7.1
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but it's still not working. The "Could not SQLConnect" error persist.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that you have the library `/usr/local/lib/libtdsodbc.so`?

I ran into a similar error. I fixed my error following this guide at [link](https://gist.github.com/Bouke/10454272).

I believe you may not have installed the drivers for `freetds`, which you can install via `Homebrew` with:

`$ brew install freetds --with-unixodbc`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try emehex's answer from here:

[Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server'? Sym linking issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44527452/cant-open-lib-odbc-driver-13-for-sql-server-sym-linking-issue)

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/etc/odbcinst.ini /etc/odbcinst.ini
sudo ln -s /usr/local/etc/odbc.ini /etc/odbc.ini
```