# Can't open lib ODBC Driver 17 OSX

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, odbc, pyodbc

I have installed the driver on my Mac and tried to run the rust, unfortunately I keep getting the following message:

Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")

I have followed the following instructions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

My Python code to establish the connection looks like this:

```
con = pyodbc.connect(
                r'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};'
                r'SERVER=;'
                r'DATABASE=;'
                r'UID=;'
                r'PWD='
                )
```

On Windows I don't have any problems running this, but on my Mac I can't get the code running even when I have the driver installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone ever gets the same problem as I have, you have to use the solution found at:

[Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server'? Sym linking issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44527452/cant-open-lib-odbc-driver-13-for-sql-server-sym-linking-issue?rq=1)