# cant-open-lib-odbc-driver-13-for-sql-server-sym-linking-issue

Tags: sql-server, django, python-3.x, pyodbc

I have de same problem as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44527452/cant-open-lib-odbc-driver-13-for-sql-server-sym-linking-issue), but the solutions are not working for me

my computer is in debian9

more details :
result of `odbcinst -j` is :

```
unixODBC 2.3.4
DRIVERS............: /etc/odbcinst.ini
SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /etc/odbc.ini
FILE DATA SOURCES..: /etc/ODBCDataSources
USER DATA SOURCES..: /root/.odbc.ini
SQLULEN Size.......: 8
SQLLEN Size........: 8
SQLSETPOSIROW Size.: 8

ls -l /etc/*.ini

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 déc.  12  2016 /etc/odbc.ini
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 nov.   7 14:58 /etc/odbcinst.ini
```

thank's for your help
(sorry for my poor english)
Christophe

Comment: Make sure that `odbcinst.ini` is in the proper directory, and that the path to the binary file in `odbcinst.ini` is correct. Please also include more details in your question if you can: your `odbcinst.ini` file contents and location would be a big help. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i think my odbcinst.ini is empty, i try send you more details

Answer (score 0):

If you `odbcinst.ini` is missing - typically in `/etc` - it should look something like this:

```
[ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server
Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql13/lib64/libmsodbcsql-13.1.so
UsageCount=1
```

It is important the the `Driver=` line points to the location of the driver. The instructions for installing the latest (v17 instead of v13) of the driver are located here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017