# Jupyter: can't connect to MS SQL Server with pyodbc

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, odbc

I can't connect to MS SQL Server in my Jupyter notebook:

Code:

```
import pyodbc
pyodbc.drivers()
```

Output:

```
[]
```

Nothing!

Connection string:

```
db_connection = pyodbc.connect('Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};'
                               'Server=Server IP;'
                               'Database=DB_Main;'
                               'UID=DB_User;'
                               'PWD=secrets')
```

Every conceivable driver string I use I get the same basic message:

> Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib
>   'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server' : file not found (0)
>   (SQLDriverConnect)")

Since `pyodbc.drivers()` isn't showing anything it would seem that the installation is borked.

**UPDATE:**
I was unable to get the symlink solutions with the INI files to work as suggested here: [Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server'? Sym linking issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44527452/cant-open-lib-odbc-driver-13-for-sql-server-sym-linking-issue)

Directly specifying the driver as shown in the answer below is what worked.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server'? Sym linking issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44527452/cant-open-lib-odbc-driver-13-for-sql-server-sym-linking-issue)

Comment: @EvandroPomatti See my answer below. I tried all that stuff -- symlinks etc. Resorted to just directly specifying the driver -- see my answer below. I don't remember where I found this solution.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up having to directly specify the driver like this:

```
driver = '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so'
ip = "10.10.10.1"
db_connection = pyodbc.connect(
    driver = driver,
    Server = ip,
    Port = "49189",
    Database = "project_db",
    UID = "db_user",
    PWD = "secrets" )
```

Installed TDS and the ODBC packages on the server then searched for the `libtdsodbc.so` driver using `find`. This worked perfectly though there may be other simpler ways.

Comment: I managed to get it working too and without specifying, if you want you may take a look here: https://github.com/evandropomatti/pyodbc-docker

Answer (score 0):

Try Installing ODBC Drivers (13/17) and your pyodbc.drivers() should return the driver info, you should be able connect then.

Comment: Are you answering the main question or do you have another question? Please this space should be used only to post answers!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30672180)