# connecting to sql-server via Python when authentication type is azure active directory

Tags: python, sql-server, azure-active-directory

I am trying to see if it's possible to connect to SQL Server via Python when the authentication type is:

> Azure Active Directory - Universal with MFA support

I can connect to this data base using Azure. The lines below show the credentials needed when connecting through azure data studio:

```
connection type : Microsoft SQL Server
server : ***.net
Authentication Type : Azure Active Directory - Universal with MFA support
account : ***.***@mycompany.com
database : target
Server group : default
```

I have looked everywhere on the web, and every thing I see regarding connecting to SQL Server via Python is when the Authentication Type is SQL login. Please help if you know the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can. Refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/using-azure-active-directory?view=sql-server-2017#example-connection-strings) for more details.

> (Windows driver only.) AAD Interactive Authentication uses Azure
>   Multi-factor Authentication technology to set up connection. In this
>   mode, by providing the login ID, an Azure Authentication dialog is
>   triggered and allows the user to input the password to complete the
>   connection. The username is passed in the connection string.

```
server=Server;database=Database;UID=UserName;Authentication=ActiveDirectoryInteractive;
```

I have tested this on my side and my test code is as below.

```
import pyodbc
server = 'tonytest920.database.windows.net'
database = 'tonytest'
driver = '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER='+driver+';SERVER='+server +
                      ';PORT=1433;DATABASE='+database+';Authentication=ActiveDirectoryInteractive;UID=xx@xx.onmicrosoft.com')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute(
    "select * from Persons")
row = cursor.fetchone()
while row:
    print(str(row[0]) + " " + str(row[1]))
    row = cursor.fetchone()
```

**Note**: You need to install [adalsql.dll](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48742) first. Remember to choose `ENU\x86\adalsql.msi`.

Comment: I'm getting this error:

Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")

Comment: @BenNicholl For this issue, take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44527452/cant-open-lib-odbc-driver-13-for-sql-server-sym-linking-issue