# Dockerfile can't open ODBC driver 17 and fails during running the python script

Tags: docker, odbc, dockerfile, containers, docker-machine

I have create in docker 2 contains 1 to run the MSSQL server and the other a python container with the code to read data from an .xlsx file and inserting it into SQL server.

My **Dockerfile** has the below code :

```
FROM python:3.6-alpine
RUN apk update
RUN apk add gcc libc-dev g++ libffi-dev libxml2 unixodbc-dev mariadb-dev postgresql-dev
FROM continuumio/miniconda3

ADD test.py /

RUN apt-get update -y \
    && apt install python3 -y \
    && apt install python3-pip -y \
    && apt install python3-venv -y \
    && python3 -m venv venv


RUN apt-get -y install curl

**#Install FreeTDS and dependencies for PyODBC**
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y tdsodbc unixodbc-dev \
 && apt install unixodbc-bin -y  \
 && apt-get clean -y

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y tdsodbc unixodbc-dev
RUN apt install unixodbc-bin -y
RUN apt-get clean -y

RUN pip install pandas
RUN pip install pyodbc
RUN pip install DateTime
RUN pip install multiprocess
RUN pip install threaded

CMD [ "python", "./test.py" ]
```

It compiles successfully but fails every time i run the container with the below error :

pyodbc.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")

I have been trying this for days but found no resolution.

Believe I need to install ODBC driver 17, if so how do I add it to my Dockerfile?

Comment: Did you find a solution? Same problem here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server'? Sym linking issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44527452/cant-open-lib-odbc-driver-13-for-sql-server-sym-linking-issue)