# connect to sql server from mac via sqlalchemy

Tags: python, macos, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I am switching from windows to mac. the below code works fine in windows. what would I have to adapt please? I get:

```
pyodbc.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'SQL Server Native Client 11.0' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")

import urllib
import sqlalchemy as sa

def get_engine():
    connection_string = urllib.parse.quote_plus(
            "DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};" 
            "SERVER=bla
            "DATABASE=bla
            "Trusted_Connection=yes"
        )
    return sa.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}".format(connection_string))
```

Answer (score 1):

The code seems okay ! Did you try this answer from a similar question ?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/44546783/12497001

It seems that SQLAlchemy relies on a driver that it cannot find on your Mac.

Comment: thanks and I have to use: "DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};"