# Cannot Connect to SQL-Server via Python on MacOS with M1

Tags: python, sql-server, macos, database-connection, connection-string

Environment

- System: Darwin Kernel Version 21.6.0
- Python: 3.11.1
- pyodbc: 4.0.35
- OS: MacOS Monterey (12.6.3)
- DB: MS SQL Server (on vscode I am using mssql)
- driver: ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server

I am trying to connect to my company's SQL server with Python (Jupyter Environment) using `pyodbc` module on my machine and I am getting an error. I have followed [this installation guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/install-microsoft-odbc-driver-sql-server-macos?view=sql-server-2017) and I still can't get it to run.

Here is my connection string:

I got the driver from `pyodbc.drivers()` as `['ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server']` so therefore,

```
cnxn_str = (
            "DRIVER={'ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server'};"
            "SERVER=companyserver.net;"
            "DATABASE=somedatabase;"
            "UID=myuid;"
            "PWD=mypassword;")
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(cnxn_str)
```

This is the error I am getting:

> Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib ''ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server'' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")

Here is what I have tried:

I tried doing the troubleshoot provided in the Microsoft ODBC driver installation document:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/etc/odbcinst.ini /etc/odbcinst.ini
sudo ln -s /usr/local/etc/odbc.ini /etc/odbc.ini
```

and it didn't work either, secondly I tried `odbcinst -j` command and here is what I got:

```
DRIVERS............: /opt/homebrew/etc/odbcinst.ini
SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /opt/homebrew/etc/odbc.ini
FILE DATA SOURCES..: /opt/homebrew/etc/ODBCDataSources
USER DATA SOURCES..: /Users/myname/.odbc.ini
SQLULEN Size.......: 8
SQLLEN Size........: 8
SQLSETPOSIROW Size.: 8
```

```
cat /opt/homebrew/etc/odbcinst.ini
```

```
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server
Driver=/opt/homebrew/lib/libmsodbcsql.18.dylib
UsageCount=1
```

Using the driver I made the connection string:

```
cnxn_str = (
            "DRIVER={'/opt/homebrew/lib/libmsodbcsql.18.dylib'};"
            "SERVER=companyserver.net;"
            "DATABASE=somedatabase;"
            "UID=myuid;"
            "PWD=mypassword;")
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(cnxn_str)
```

and I am still getting this error:

> Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib ''/opt/homebrew/lib/libmsodbcsql.18.dylib' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")

Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong?? Any help would be helpful.

Thank you so much!

Comment: What does `ls -la /opt/homebrew/lib/libmsodbcsql.18.dylib` output? There shouldn't be anything at all related in `/usr/local`, as per the advice on the page you linked, _Additionally, the Homebrew default directory changed with the ARM64 architecture, to `/opt/homebrew`. The paths in the Driver files section use the x64 Homebrew paths, which default to `/usr/local`, so your file paths will vary accordingly._

Comment: You'll notice that `''ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server''` in the error message is two sets of `'` characters, not single sets of `"` characters. Have you tried `"DRIVER={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};"` without the `'` characters as per the documentation?

Answer (score 1):

uninstalling and installing `unixodbc` didn't work for me. I did these steps:

- `brew tap microsoft/mssql-release https://github.com/Microsoft/homebrew-mssql-release`
  ,then
- `brew install msodbcsql mssql-tools`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution to my question:
I used [Rene B.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52651349/21352449) answer to the question to solve it. In my case `brew install msodbcsql mssql-tools` 
wasn't properly installed. I also uninstall and reinstalled `unixodbc` and then installed  `msodbcsql mssql-tools` which finally worked for me.