# How to correctly install and run pyodbc and releated drivers on MacBook Pro M1?

Tags: python, sql-server, macos, odbc, pyodbc

I read many posts/blogs about this topic but none worked for me, and I'm stuck now.
Please, be kind to me, I'm new to macOS as well as the SQL/ODBC world. I'm here to learn something new.

Essentially, I migrated from Windows to Apple (the company's laptop). Here is the general information regarding my new laptop.

- System: Darwin Kernel Version 23.0.0
- Python: 3.9.6 (stored in `/usr/bin/python3`, this is the native python installation, weird because I thought on M1 chip the location should be `/opt/homebrew`. I'm not working in a venv )
- pyodbc: 5.0.1 (installed via `pip3 install --no-binary :all: pyodbc`)
- OS: MacOS Sonoma (14.0)
- Chip: Apple M1 Pro
- Driver: SQL Server (this is what I wrote in my original Windows-based Python code)
- IDE: VS Code 1.85.1 (Universal)

In my previous laptop, I build a code base on `pyodbc` and it used to work correctly. Here a snippet

```
import pyodbc as po

po.connect("DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=*company server*; DATABASE=*company database*")
```

Now this code is not working on my new macOS-based laptop.

I followed the following sources (and many others):

- [Linkedin guide](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/connect-azure-sql-database-python-apple-silicon-m1-mac-kenji-otsuka/)
- [Microsoft guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/install-microsoft-odbc-driver-sql-server-macos?view=sql-server-2017)
- [Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server'? Sym linking issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44527452/cant-open-lib-odbc-driver-13-for-sql-server-sym-linking-issue/52651349#52651349)
- [Cannot Connect to SQL-Server via Python on MacOS with M1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75668427/cannot-connect-to-sql-server-via-python-on-macos-with-m1)
- [How to properly install pyodbc and drivers on M1 mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71119470/how-to-properly-install-pyodbc-and-drivers-on-m1-mac)
- ChatGPT (just for fun)

In a nutshell, I performed these steps:

```
% brew install unixodbc

% /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
% brew tap microsoft/mssql-release https://github.com/Microsoft/homebrew-mssql-release
% brew update
% HOMEBREW_ACCEPT_EULA=Y brew install msodbcsql18 mssql-tools18

% sudo ln -s /usr/local/etc/odbcinst.ini /etc/odbcinst.in
% sudo ln -s /usr/local/etc/odbc.ini /etc/odbc.inii
```

Moreover, whatever it was needed, I:

- Replaced `usr/local` with `opt/homebrew` as suggested in the Microsoft guide.
- Uninstalled and reinstalled unixodbc
- Replaced `DRIVER={SQL Server}` with `DRIVER={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Serever}` or 17 or 13.

Here the results of some commands (both python and terminal) I found by following the above sources.

The `odbcinst -j` command:

```
unixODBC 2.3.12 
DRIVERS............: /opt/homebrew/etc/odbcinst.ini SYSTEM DATA
SOURCES: /opt/homebrew/etc/odbc.ini FILE DATA SOURCES..:
/opt/homebrew/etc/ODBCDataSources USER DATA SOURCES..:
/Users/mottad/.odbc.ini SQLULEN Size.......: 8 SQLLEN Size........: 8
SQLSETPOSIROW Size.: 8
```

The `cat /opt/homebrew/etc/odbcinst.ini` command:

```
[ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server
Driver=/opt/homebrew/lib/libmsodbcsql.18.dylib
UsageCount=3

[ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Driver=/opt/homebrew/lib/libmsodbcsql.17.dylib
UsageCount=2

[ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server
Driver=/usr/local/lib/libmsodbcsql.13.dylib
UsageCount=1
```

The `pyodbc.drivers()` command (in python clearly)

```
'ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server',  'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server', 
'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server']
```

Finally, here is the python code I'm trying to run in Visual Studio Code (Jupyter Notebook).

```
import pyodbc as po
po.connect("DRIVER={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};SERVER=*company server*; DATABASE=*company database*")
```

> OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]SSL Provider: [error:0A000086:SSL routines::certificate verify failed:self-signed certificate] (-1) (SQLDriverConnect)')

```
po.connect("DRIVER={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};SERVER=*company server*; DATABASE=*company database*")
```

> ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/usr/local/lib/libmsodbcsql.13.dylib' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")

```
po.connect("DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=*company server*; DATABASE=*company database*")
```

> ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")

```
po.connect("DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=*company server*; DATABASE=*company database*")
```

> InterfaceError: ('28000', "[28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL
> Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user ''. (18456)
> (SQLDriverConnect)")

For this last trial, something seems going on. I tried to add UID and PWD but it did not work. Furthermore, let me say it was not necessary to add UID and PWD on my Windows-based laptop.

```
po.connect("DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=*company server*; DATABASE=*company database*; UID=*my company email/ID*; PWD=*my company psw*")
```

> InterfaceError: ('28000', "[28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL
> Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user '*my company email/ID*'.
> (18456) (SQLDriverConnect)")

**Question:**
Could you please kindly help me to solve this issue?

Comment: Aside... Ideally `DRIVER={SQL Server}` should never work on non-Windows computers. This tries to use the deprecated _SQL Server Native Client_ library that hasn't seen any feature updates since SQL Server 2012 days and Microsoft (finally) stopped shipping it altogether as of SQL Server 2022.

Comment: Is your UID is formatted like an email address? That likely means that you cannot use SQL Login authentication (username and password-based with the UID and PWD parameters) because the targeted SQL Server instance requires Active Directory (or Kerberos) authentication or Microsoft Entra authentication. Have you asked the server managers/DBAs how you should be connecting to it from macOS?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning my UID is an email address. It could also be like this "surname + first-name-letter". I tried both options but it returned an error. Just fyi, I downloaded Azure Data Studio. Here, I can connect to the SQL database. Last but not least, I've not asked to the server manager yet